# How to handle WKT data in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, wkt

I have data in this format:

```
POINT(73.0166738279393 33.6788721326803)
MULTILINESTRING((73.0131224998036 33.679001500419,73.0119635003153 33.678392400389,73.0119205001311 33.6783781002692),(73.0131224998036 33.679001500419,73.0136031002029 33.6783443999742),(73.0136031002029 33.6783443999742,73.0147099372139 33.67685138958),(73.0147099372139 33.67685138958,73.0150124997272 33.6770292997624,73.0154158996241 33.6773507003746,73.0157677998441 33.6776577999676,73.016042399737 33.6779721004322,73.0162998999205 33.6783149004124,73.0166738279393 33.6788721326803))
```

Now I want to draw it on Google Maps in Android. I make an array of names and coordinates.

```
ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>
coordinates.add(tvcoor.getText().toString());
```

This produces an error: when I run my application, it stops forcefully.
And how can I draw it on a map?

Comment: Gilles i add if statement because the textView has also received another data. but i want only coordinates data stores into the array list

Comment: thanks i have solve my error atleast

Comment: tell me is this code is correct for adding values into array list form textviewif((tvTextIn.equals(new String ("POINT")))||(tvTextIn.equals(new String ("MULTILINES"))))
   {
   coordinates.add(tvcoor.getText().toString());
   }

Comment: when i run this code ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String> coordinates.add(tvcoor.getText().toString()); it doesnot store values in the array list all values are null it created a size but all are null

Comment: did u get textview value? . please post your full code.

Comment: is there any way in android to parse WKT data. extract lat long from it

Comment: i stores WKT data (mentioned in my post) into a variable form textview then i add this data into ararylist for(int i=0; i<values.length(); i++)
   {
   coor.add(values.split(",").toString());
   } but it stores [[Ljava.lang.String;@44f08800] at every position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ,

```
String str;
ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

First get string from textview.

```
str = textview.getText().toString();
```

Second remove brackets.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(", "");
str = str.replaceAll("\\)", "");
```

Then split with comma and add values to arraylist.

```
String[] commatokens = str.split(",");
        for (String commatoken : commatokens) {
            System.out.println("-" + commatoken + "-");
            coordinates.add(commatoken);
        }
```

Then we get separate coordinates value at index position ,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {

            String[] tokens = coordinates.get(i).split("\\s");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                System.out.println("-" + token + "-");
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks rajesh for help but i can't understand the last step and when i send this coordiantes arraylist in the mapactivity and then from mapactivity to overlay class and draw a point

Comment: Intent in = getIntent();
          loc = in.getStringArrayListExtra("stringname");
          
           mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            proj = mapView.getProjection();
            
            overlay = new MyOverlay(locations);                   and draw a point like this                                     public MyOverlay(List<String> locations) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 
 GeoPoint mp = new GeoPoint((int)(Integer.parseInt(locations.get(0))*1E6), (int)(Integer.parseInt(locations.get(1))*1E6));                       then the application stop unexpectedly

Comment: it has some problem at first position it saves [0] = POINT(73.0166738279393 33.6788721326803)
MULTILINESTRING((73.0131224998036 33.679001500419; [1] = 73.0119635003153 33.678392400389; then again [2] = POINT(73.0166738279393 33.6788721326803)
MULTILINESTRING((73.0131224998036 33.679001500419;

Comment: when i use \\s it does not split first line and i when i used " " it split the last values

Comment: thanks rajesh great help from you i have solved this issue. now going for drawing on google map

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has this same scenario, I found an open source library called [JTS Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm), which has the capability to parse WKT strings in Java. A basic example from my application looks like this:

```
WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
Geometry geometry = wktReader.read(routeResponse.get(yourWKTMultilineString);
```

You can then iterate through the individual lines like so:

```
for(int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < geometry.getNumGeometries(); lineIndex++){
    Geometry lineGeometry = geometry.getGeometryN(lineIndex);
    //... other stuff
}
```

If necessary, you can obtain the individual coordinates of each line like so:

```
Coordinate[] lineCoordinates = lineGeometry.getCoordinates();
```

Note that the above is a very general example which follows the OP's code.

Ultimately, this might save others from having to roll their own WKT parser.

---

**Nutiteq-Specific Code:**
In my case, I needed to draw a multiline string as a vector layer on a [Nutiteq map](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d). I realize the OP was asking about the google map android API, however in case any reader is also using Nutiteq (or if this algorithm is relevant for other map APIs), this is the nutiteq specific code:

```
geomLayer.clear(); // clear the old vector data

Projection projection = geomLayer.getProjection(); // Map's projection type

// Iterate through the individual lines of our multi-line geometry
for(int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < geometry.getNumGeometries(); lineIndex++){
    Geometry lineGeometry = geometry.getGeometryN(lineIndex);
    ArrayList<MapPos> linePositions = new ArrayList<MapPos>(lineGeometry.getCoordinates().length);

    // Iterate through this line's coordinates
    for(Coordinate coordinate : lineGeometry.getCoordinates()){
        // My server returns coordinates in WGS84/EPSG:4326 projection while the map
        // uses EPSG3857, so it is necessary to convert before adding to the
        // array list.
        MapPos linePosition = new MapPos(projection.fromWgs84(coordinate.x, coordinate.y));
        linePositions.add(linePosition);
    }

    // Finally, add the line data to the vector layer
    Line line = new Line(linePositions, new DefaultLabel("some label"), lineStyle), null);
    geomLayer.add(line);
}
```

Note that the `lineStyleSet` and `geomLayer` are created previously in the activity's `onCreate` and can be researched [here](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Vectorobjects). The `geomLayer` is simple; here is my `lineStyleSet`:

Note about lineStyle, it was created previously and is saved as an instance variable, like so:

```
Bitmap lineMarker = UnscaledBitmapLoader.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.line);

this.lineStyleSet = new StyleSet<LineStyle>();
LineStyle lineStyle = LineStyle.builder().setLineJoinMode(LineStyle.NO_LINEJOIN).setWidth(0.2f).setColor(Color.RED).setBitmap(lineMarker).build();
lineStyleSet.setZoomStyle(minZoom, lineStyle);
```

Answer (score 1):

A **WKT** (well-known-text) file describes an ISO 19107 Geometry. Personally I try to avoid re-inventing the wheel, or "mess" with them in self written parsers ( you never know, whether your function covers all situation just because it worked once).

So here's another nice looking open source API, with examples, tutorials:

http://docs.geotools.org/

And here the WKTParser class

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/text/WKTParser.html

**Android Studio:**
Simply add this to your app `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    /* your other dependencies */
    compile 'org.opengis:geoapi:3.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I wrote to convert a **simple** (no holes etc.) polygon given in WKT into an array of LatLang:

```
public static LatLng[] GetPolygonPoints(String poligonWkt){
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d*\\.\\d+)\\s(\\d*\\.\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(poligonWkt);
    String point;

    while (m.find()){
        point =  poligonWkt.substring(m.start(), m.end());
        points.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(m.group(2)), Double.parseDouble(m.group(1))));
    }
    return points.toArray(new LatLng[points.size()]);
}
```

You can then use the array to add the polygon on the map:

```
LatLng[] points = GeographyHelper.GetPolygonPoints(shapeWkt);

Polygon p = mMap.addPolygon(
   new PolygonOptions()
      .add(points)
      .strokeWidth(4)
      .strokeColor(Color.RED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Paul's answer, since his answer helped me so much...

```
private void setUpMap(SomeObjectWithLocationAsWKT r) {

    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
    LineString line = null;
    Coordinate lineCentroid = null;
    Coordinate[] lineCoordinates = null;

    // if our object's WKT geometry is not null - map it
    if (r.geowkt != null) {

        // use the JTS (Java Topology Suite) WKTReader to read that WKT!
        try {
            line = (LineString) wktReader.read(r.geowkt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // using (JTS) again to getCoordinates of the linestring
        lineCoordinates = line.getCoordinates();

        // Iterate through the line's coordinates & assign to List<LatLng> points
        for(Coordinate coordinate : lineCoordinates){
            points.add(new LatLng(coordinate.x, coordinate.y));
        }

        // add Polyline to Google Map
        Polyline p = mMap.addPolyline(
        new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(points)
        .width(4)
        .color(Color.RED));
    }
}

// an example of zooming to the centroid of the WKT geometry 
// again, using (JTS - Java Topology Suite)
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = null; 
    WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
    LineString line = null;
    Coordinate lineCentroid = null; 

    // if our object's WKT geometry is not null - zoom to it
    if (r.geowkt != null) {
        try {
            line = (LineString) wktReader.read(r.geowkt);
            lineCentroid = line.getCentroid().getCoordinate();
            latLng = new LatLng(lineCentroid.x, lineCentroid.y);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // just default to whatever location was passed in
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    }
    CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 19);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
}
```

Comment: Well Known Text standard cover every kind of geospatial object and this solution seems to -at least try- convert it into a LineString. It's likely to crash.