# set color to particular area in google map using polygons overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i need to color a particular area of google map. I have tried the  [polygon overlay example.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays). Here the co-ordinates used like below way:

```
var triangleCoords = [   
    new google.maps.LatLng(23.8099144,90.40607589999999,0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(24.8199144,86.40607589999999,0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.8299144,92.40607589999999,0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(23.8099144,90.40607589999999,0)
];
```

But i have the area coordinates like the below format:

> 89.90277900000007,22.36819100000007,0 89.90277900000007,22.36833399999999,0 89.90334400000013,22.36861000000009,0 89.903611,22.36889000000003,0 89.90416700000004,22.36917099999998,0 89.90499900000009,22.37001000000014,0 89.90499900000009,22.37111000000006,0 89.905281,22.37138800000008,0 89.905281,22.37833300000009,0 89.90333500000007,22.37833300000009,0 89.90166400000005,22.37527899999996,0 89.901391,22.3750010000001,089.90166400000005,22.36944400000003,0 89.90166400000005,22.36929200000004,0 89.90166400000005,22.36916600000013,0 89.90110800000001,22.36861000000009,0 89.90132199999998,22.36829099999999,0 89.90135199999997,22.368179,0 89.901391,22.36805600000009,0 89.90277900000007,22.36805600000009,0 89.90277900000007,22.36819100000007,0

Now **how i can use this area co-ordinates value into the code**. The value is comes from database single field and it's really difficult to incorporate one by one into the object like:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(89.90277900000007,22.36819100000007,0),
new google.maps.LatLng(89.90277900000007,22.36833399999999,0),
.
.
.
new google.maps.LatLng(89.90277900000007,22.36819100000007,0),
```

please give me a suitable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Well-known text (WKT) from MySQL to Google Maps polygons with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482303/convert-well-known-text-wkt-from-mysql-to-google-maps-polygons-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code...

```
var res = "89.90277900000007,22.36819100000007,....,0 89.90277900000007,22.36819100000007,0";
resArray = res.split(" ");
var triangleCoords = [];

for(var i=0; i<resArray.length; i++){
    triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(resArray[0]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.

Get all data from the db, then split it by space(In whatever server side language you are using or using javascript). Then you will get an array, try to loop that array and build the latlng object. But split by space is not the best method, because there may be data in the db without space.

Note: new google.maps.LatLng(23.8099144,90.40607589999999,0), here the last arg is not required. only latitude and longitude will work.

Comment: Is there any better way rather than looping and creating array? can i declare full of my co-ordinates into a single object?