# Save Google Api polygon as openlayers string

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I want to save my polygon which user draws it into the strings like:

```
"SRID=4326;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((......)))"
```

Is there anyway to do it ?
I don't want to use encodeString from google API

thanks

Comment: The answer to [Convert Well-known text (WKT) from MySQL to Google Maps polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482303/convert-well-known-text-wkt-from-mysql-to-google-maps-polygons-with-php/18112446#18112446) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution and hope this also can help anybody out there with the same problem as mine.

[Convert Google Maps Polygon (API V3) to Well Known Text (WKT) Geometry Expression](http://cartometric.com/blog/2014/06/06/convert-google-maps-polygon-api-v3-to-well-known-text-wkt-geometry-expression/)

```
function GMapPolygonToWKT(poly) {
    // Start the Polygon Well Known Text (WKT) expression
    wkt = "SRID=4326;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON(";

    var paths = poly.getPaths();

    for(var i=0; i<paths.getLength(); i++) {
        var path = paths.getAt(i);

        // Open a ring grouping in the Polygon Well Known Text
        wkt += "(";
        for(var j=0; j<path.getLength(); j++) {

            // setCenteradd each vertice and anticipate another vertice (trailing comma)
            wkt += path.getAt(j).lng().toString()
                + " "
                + path.getAt(j).lat().toString()
                +",";
        }
        // Also close the ring grouping and anticipate another ring (trailing comma)
        wkt += path.getAt(0).lng().toString()
            + " "
            + path.getAt(0).lat().toString()
            + "),";
    }
    // resolve the last trailing "," and close the Polygon
    wkt = wkt.substring(0, wkt.length - 1) + "))";
    return wkt;
}
```

This is a valid string for GeoDjango postgis database.

Comment: Your function accepts an argument `poly`, which is then completely ignored.  But it does refer to a variable `geoField`; where did that come from?  The original version of this code used that argument: `var paths = poly.getPaths();`, why not just pass `geoField` into the function when you call it?

Comment: yes, you are right I changed it to poly, geoField is my global variable which not related to this answer.