# Android - Creating a WKT string out of a list of lat/long coordinates

Tags: android, geometry, wkt

Having a list of objects that contain latitude and longitude values, I'd like to create a WKT `String` to have a `POLYGON` WKT in my Android application. This `POLYGON` will be send later to the server among other data as part of a json.

I know it's possible to do it using [ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/packages.html) lib, but this solution one seems too robust for my usage. This would be the only usage of the lib in my app and adding this lib increased in 30Mb the size of the apk. I was expecting to find a more lightweight solution for this matter.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368586/how-to-handle-wkt-data-in-android) addresses the exact oposite of what I need. There are a couple libs mentioned on the answers but, checking their documentation, neither seems to create a WKT, only being able to create coordinates based on a WKT `String` instead.

How can I create a WKT String, having a list of latitude/longitude coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how the latitude/longitude coordinates are stored, so I assume they are stored in a `double` array containing interleaved latitude/longitude coordinates. The following function generates a polygon WKT from the array, assuming the polygon contains no holes.

```
 public static String polygonWkt(double[] latlon){
     if(latlon.length%2 != 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("latlon length is not even");
     StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
     builder.append("POLYGON((");
     for(int i=0;i<latlon.length;i+=2){
         if(i>0){
             builder.append(",");
         }
         builder.append(latlon[i]+" "+latlon[i+1]);
     }
     builder.append("))");
     return builder.toString();
 }
```

Also [posted in GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/peteroupc/7fd0f0a570147b43e09550b146ee93da).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The coordinates are actually stored in a object that has `double getLatitude()` and `double getLongitude()` methods. I've edited my question to make it clear. But I guess I can figure out how to make it work now using your idea.